# Which countries besides the United States allow voting in federal elections without a voter ID?

Tags: election, voting

When trying to locate a answer for this question I was only able to find results which provided examples of countries which did *not* allow voting without some form of ID.

Besides certain states within the United States which do not require ID for voting, what other countries allow voting without having to show some form of ID?